# Falsy code executed in fabricjs _fireOverOutEvents

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, mouseout

Good day, I'm using `fabricjs`, and it works well for me.
I did however recently come across a JavaScript thing I cannot explain, and that I only detected on `fabricjs` (across all browsers).

Note: I am using `1.7.11` of `fabricjs`.

It occurs on `mouse:out` events. 
It's only side-effect is to bloat the browser console with:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fire' of null
>       at klass._fireOverOutEvents (fabric.js:9717)
>       ...

It goes like this:

[image: screenshot, falsy yet executed]

This is vanilla `fabric.js` (i.e. not my code).

As you can see, `target` is `undefined`, so the `if` block is not executed. So far, that is expected. Now for the odd part.

`this._hoveredTarget` is `null` (see debugger view below). 
The `else if` block should not be executed, yet it is.

[Debugging view of falsy "else if" being executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPcVB.png)

I tried to fix it with variants like `this._hoveredTarget !== null` and `this._hoveredTarget != null`, but it still goes there when `this._hoveredTarget` is `null`.

I never saw this before. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide proof that `this._hoveredTarget` is null?

Comment: check before else if,  `this._hoveredTarget = target`, after that else if executing

Comment: I added a debugger view of the code when the problem occurs.

Comment: You have to have some code in canvas.on('mouse:out') that is killing canvas._hoveredTarget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this cannot happen just because a bug in the code. an IF is an IF.
What can happen is that you have some event handling on `mouse:out` that is happening before that line that is erroring and that event handler is deleting the reference to `this._hoverTarget`.

This is still a bug in my opinion since if custom code is allowed the condition must be checked again before accessing the variable as an object.

Current version of fabricJS 1.7.17 has a different code in place:

[image]

this.hoveredTarget is saved as reference immediately so that whatever it happens to hoveredTarget you are safe.

You should upgrade maybe.